# Masonry / Isotope Full-width Stamp In-place

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-isotope, jquery-masonry

I've been experimenting with Masonry and Isotope, and I noticed that it includes a `stamp` option. I've been trying to leverage this feature to create a full-width stamp in-place.

I have been experimenting with the `stamp` code found in the [isotope documentation](http://isotope.metafizzy.co/beta/methods.html#stamp). The approach I've taken is listed below:

```
$demo.find('button').on( 'click', function() {
    $stampElem.attr('style', '');

    // stamp or unstamp element
    if ( isStamped ) {
        $container.isotope( 'unstamp', $stampElem );
    } else {
        $stampElem.attr('style', 'width: 100%;');
        $container.isotope( 'stamp', $stampElem );
    }
    // trigger layout
    $container.isotope('layout');
    isStamped = !isStamped;
});
```

However, using this method has unexpected results:

- The stamped block ends up at the top of the container, and all other blocks show up underneath
- The stamped block doesn't return to its previous position

How can I create a full-width stamp that stays in-place (i.e. pushes blocks before it up, and pushed blocks after it down)?

*[Interactive example here](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/FKHnJ).*

Comment: Please be sure to use the tag autocomplete system.  You needlessly created two new tags.

Comment: Sorry; I thought that I had. That is my mistake.